# How can I configure Delayed jobs to not wait for a task before starting the others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, delayed-job

I am using Delayed jobs for my Ruby app hosted in Heroku to perform a very long task that can take up to 5 minutes. 
I've noticed that, in development mode at least, when this task is running the ones that come afterwards are not started until that one finishes. I would like other tasks to be able to start running without having to wait for the other to finish (to have at least 3 concurrent tasks, for example).
I don't wish to increase the number of workers in Heroku ($$$). 
I noticed the 'pool' param in delayed jobs but I don't fully understand if this is what I need or how to use it.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/README.md

I achieved it using threads in the task code, but maybe this is not the best way to do it.

If you could tell me exactly how I could achieve concurrency in delayed jobs I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A DJ worker only runs a single job at a time. If you want concurrent processing of your background jobs, you'll need multiple background workers.

You are way better off implementing [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).

Comment: Got it. What does the pool do then?

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon It lets you run multiple workers. You can do this in a single Heroku dyno, but because it uses process forking it's memory intensive. You might need to use [a tool like this](https://github.com/salsify/delayed_job_worker_pool) to avoid issues with daemonization on Heroku.

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon I'd like to reiterate that Sidekiq is a vastly superior option, supports better architecture, is still free, and requires only minor changes to your codebase. The author, Mike Perham, is also an active StackOverflow user and answers questions related to Sidekiq frequently. Just make the switch and stop fighting with outdated DJ.

Comment: I will use resque since I read that sidekiq requires the code to be thread safe which I really don't think mine is (I use a lot of global variables). Thank you for your help!